# Which array type to use to store two strings referenced by one key

Tags: vb.net

Simple question. Have a list of file paths (strings) to pair together, and store in an array of some type. Example: several hundred pairs to be referenced later and compared once a list is compiled of the matches and stored in an array. What would be the best array type to store the two linked strings?

C:\PATH\path1.jpg, C:\PATH2\path2.jpg

Thank you in advance and excuse my ignorance.

Comment: You could use a [Dictionary(Of String,String())](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x525za90(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `two strings referenced by one key` what/where is the key?

Comment: It depends. If the list of filepaths for the first string are always going to be unique, you could use a Dictionary collection and have the first string of the pair as the key(this must be unique) and the second string as the value. This is only really useful if you will only ever be searching using the first string stored as the key value. If you want a separate key, you could create a structure for storing the two filepaths and then create a dictionary using your separate key and the structure as the value. Or a key & tuple, or two lists or others mixtures of lists. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: What version of .Net can you use?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which represent a two paths

```
Public Class LinkedPaths
    Public Property Path1 As String
    Public Property Path2 As String
End Class
```

Then create a instance of `List(Of LinkedPaths)`

```
Dim collection As New List(Of LinkedPaths) From
{
    New LinkedPaths { .Path1 = "C:\PATH\path1.jpg", .Path2 = "C:\PATH\path2.jpg" },
    New LinkedPaths { .Path1 = "C:\PATH\path3.jpg", .Path2 = "C:\PATH\path4.jpg" }
    New LinkedPaths { .Path1 = "C:\PATH\path5.jpg", .Path2 = "C:\PATH\path6.jpg" }
}
```

Then you can iterate and compare this collection

```
For Each pathPair As LinkedPaths In collection 
    Compare(pathPair.Path1, pathPair.Path2)
Next
```

With this approach the key is instance of the `LinkedPaths` class which keep together two paths.

In case you need "real" separated key for the pair, which not mentioned in the question, but word "key" in the title get confused. Then you can use dictionary as mentioned in the comments

```
Dim collection As New Dictionary(Of String, LinkedPaths);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [`Tuple(Of String, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx). But that's just the data type inside the collection. For which collection to use, whether Array, List(Of Tuple(Of String, String)), Dictionary(Of Tuple(Of String, String)), or something else, it depends on how you'll be accessing these later.

Comment: Later on in the program, I will iterate through the list and the result of that process with be applied to both paths, as they are paired.   In this case, two images taken at the exact same time, get classified by the data in one of the images.  I will look into this `List(of tuple(of string, of string))`